# SQL Server : how to execute 2 select statements in a single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to count column first: as total number of instances of each column, second count total number of instances based on condition.

I am using this:

```
SELECT
    group_name,
    Definition_Range,
    COUNT([group_name]) AS Number_of_Clients
FROM 
    [Computer Status]
WHERE
    Definition_Range = ' 0-10 Days'
GROUP BY
    group_name,
    (SELECT COUNT([group_name]) AS Total_Clients
     FROM [Computer Status]
     GROUP BY group_name)
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Can you please provide the sample data along with the required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no meaning on below query

```
SELECT COUNT([group_name]) AS Total_Clients
         FROM [Computer Status]
         GROUP BY group_name
```

It returns same as `Number_of_Clients` written in the main query.
because you are doing `group by` of `group_name`.

> Below is perfect query

```
   SELECT
        group_name,
        Definition_Range,
        COUNT([group_name]) AS Number_of_Clients
    FROM 
        [Computer Status]
    WHERE
        Definition_Range = ' 0-10 Days'
    GROUP BY
        group_name,Definition_Range
```